# IndexWriter Constructor

Tags: java

I am using IndexWriter function in lucene with 2 parameters like `IndexWriter(directory,IndexWriterConfig)` and now I want to append already generated index for new files but my `IndexWriter` constructor cannot receive third parameter like `IndexWriter(directory,IndexWriterConfig,false)`. It just receive two parameters.

Comment: It's not clear what you expect the `false` parameter to be. Did you just make it up?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your lucene version is not supported the method `IndexWriter(directory,IndexWriterConfig,false)`,you can change a vision or change the way:

```
Directory dir=FSDirectory.open(new File("E:\\lucene_index")); 
    Analyzer analyzer=new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_42); 
    IndexWriterConfig iwc=new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_42, analyzer); 
iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND); 
    iwc.setInfoStream(System.out); 
    IndexWriter writer=new IndexWriter(dir,iwc);
```